# JavascriptInterface Android passing arguments

Tags: javascript, android, interface

I have a question if i call android function from javascript file and pass arguments to it, all arguments will be passed as Strings?

for example

Javascript

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
API.CreateCars(cars);
```

Android site

```
CreateCars(String[] cars){...}
```

It will be working? Or i should pass cars array as one string and next parse it on android site to array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check it and it's available to pass array in this way.